# Mismatch in G Suite Marketplace installation count and app User count

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps, google-workspace, drive, google-apps-marketplace

We have published an app in G Suite Marketplace, which Works with Drive App. We can see a mismatch with the installation users count shown by Google and the total number of users for the App in our side. We have got around 10k installations (new users accessed app) for our app during the previous month. However the total installation count in G Suite Marketplace is being shown as 6k since a long time, it seems the installation count has not been updated there.

Please let us know how long it will take to get the user count updated in the G Suite Marketplace listing or is there any other reason for this?